# How to gradually change a value to another over a period of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(!isWalking) {
      isWalking = true;
      var animation = setInterval(function () {$player.css({'left': "+="+boxSize/25})}, 10);
      setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(animation)},250);
      setTimeout(function(){isWalking = false},250);
}
```

This code is supposed to increase the object's x coordinate exactly by the ammount of `boxSize` over the time period of 1/4th of a second. Seems like the code has to be executed really fast so it slows down and the object can't manage to reach the destination by the time the interval is cleared. Even if I increase the interval and reduce the repetitions there stll may be some computer that wont be able to play it. Is there anything more reliable that maybe uses the number of repetitions instead of time? Also while the animation is playing the user shouldn't be able to do anything, hence the `isWalking` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.animate (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/))

```
isWalking = true;
$player.animate({
      left: futureValue
  },
  250,           // number of milliseconds animation should last
  "swing",        // easing property (see the docs)
  function() {    // callback that will run when animate completes
    isWalking = false;
});
```